# Building a frequency dictionary from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bioinformatics

I need to make a frequency dictionary from a pandas series (from the 'amino_acid' column in dataframe below) that also adds an adjacent row for each entry in the dictionary (from 'templates' column).

```
    templates   amino_acid
0   118         CAWSVGQYSNQPQHF
1   635         CASSLRGNQPQHF
2   468         CASSHGTAYEQYF
3   239         CASSLDRLSSGEQYF
4   51          CSVEDGPRGTQYF
```

My current approach of iterating through the dataframe seems to be inefficient and even an anti-pattern. How can I improve the efficiency/use best practice for doing this?

My current approach:

```py
sequence_counts = {}
seqs= list(zip(df.amino_acid, df.templates))

for seq in seqs:
    if seq[0] not in sequence_counts:
        sequence_counts[seq[0]] = 0
    sequence_counts[seq[0]] += seq[1]
```

I've seen people the below way, but can't figure out how to adjust it to add each respective 'templates' entry:

```py
sequence_counts = df['amino_acid'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

Any help/feedback would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: are you looking for `df.groupby('amino_acid',sort=False).templates.sum().to_dict()` when you say sequence counts, i am guessing you are trying to maintain the original order.

Comment: _"I've seen people the below way, but can't figure out how to adjust it to add each respective 'templates' entry:"_ this sounds like a request for help with implementing a feature, which is off-topic here on CodeReview.SE. You might want to remove this bit, or rephrase it if you think I've misunderstood the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, iterating through a dataframe usually is at odds with the spirit of dataframes and numpy arrays. They are best suited for vectorized operations, which are operations applied in bulk to rows/columns of the data structure.

Assuming that you've cast `templates` as an `int64` or similar, you can use [`pd.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to do the same sort of grouping as you are doing with your dictionary:

```py
import pandas as pd

df
        amino_acid  templates
0  CAWSVGQYSNQPQHF        118
1    CASSLRGNQPQHF        635
2    CASSHGTAYEQYF        468
3  CASSLDRLSSGEQYF        239
4    CSVEDGPRGTQYF         51
5  CASSLDRLSSGEQYF         66    # I've added this extra row here to show the effect

# these act as Series objects, so you can add together the
# grouped templates values
df.groupby('amino_acid')
# pd.groupby object

# use pd.Series.sum() to do this:
df.groupby('amino_acid').sum()

                 templates
amino_acid
CASSHGTAYEQYF          468
CASSLDRLSSGEQYF        305    # this was added for the two amino acids
CASSLRGNQPQHF          635
CAWSVGQYSNQPQHF        118
CSVEDGPRGTQYF           51
```

So what's going on in `df.groupby`? Well, you give it what to group on first. In this case, you group on the value for `amino_acid`. This creates a data structure that looks quite familiar if you've used `itertools.groupby`: tuples of `(grouping key, DataFrame)` pairs, where the `DataFrame` is a subset that matches the key. For example:

```py
tmp = [(x, y) for x,y in df.groupby('amino_acid')]

[('CASSHGTAYEQYF',       amino_acid  templates
2  CASSHGTAYEQYF        468), 
('CASSLDRLSSGEQYF',         amino_acid  templates
3  CASSLDRLSSGEQYF        239
5  CASSLDRLSSGEQYF         66), 
('CASSLRGNQPQHF',       amino_acid  templates
1  CASSLRGNQPQHF        635), 
('CAWSVGQYSNQPQHF',         amino_acid  templates
0  CAWSVGQYSNQPQHF        118), 
('CSVEDGPRGTQYF',       amino_acid  templates
4  CSVEDGPRGTQYF         51)]
```

And per the docs, [`df.sum`] will return the sum on the specified axis (1 by default). So, for `tmp[1]`, which contains two rows:

```py
tmp[1][1].sum()

amino_acid    CASSLDRLSSGEQYFCASSLDRLSSGEQYF
templates                                305
dtype: object
```

Where `305` is the sum. The `pd.groupby` object as a whole supports the `.sum` call, so we are able to call it like we did above.

```py
# Now, using `to_dict`, you can see that you want what's inside templates
df.groupby("amino_acid").sum().to_dict()

# {'templates': {'CASSHGTAYEQYF': 468, 'CASSLDRLSSGEQYF': 305, 'CASSLRGNQPQHF': 635, 'CAWSVGQYSNQPQHF': 118, 'CSVEDGPRGTQYF': 51}}

# so use the templates attribute to grab it
df.groupby("amino_acid").sum().templates.to_dict()
# {'CASSHGTAYEQYF': 468, 'CASSLDRLSSGEQYF': 305, 'CASSLRGNQPQHF': 635, 'CAWSVGQYSNQPQHF': 118, 'CSVEDGPRGTQYF': 51}
```

This applies the operations within the dataframe, which is more efficient than a loop. The analogue that you were trying to use could leverage [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the collections module, as well. It prevents the need to check for a key's existence, speeding up the loop immensely:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# specify your input type here
sequence_counts = defaultdict(int)

# it is more pythonic to use tuple-unpacking in loops
# as indexing is less readable
for amino, template in zip(df.amino_acid, df.templates):
    sequence_counts[amino] += template
```

Also, by iterating over the `zip` object directly, you don't copy data into memory. `list` will aggregate all of the members into a data structure, whereas `zip` is a generator that will just produce the members one at a time until exhausted. It's like the difference between `for x in range` and `for x in list(range)`:

```py
# This will just run for a really really really long time
for i in range(1000000000000): 
    print(i)

# This will crash your computer, it will never
# get to the print statement, because it must evaluate
# list(range) before it starts the loop
for i in list(range(1000000000000)):
    print(i)
```